# $A'$ is a subalgebra of $A$ and $B'$ is a subalgebra of $B$, then $A' \otimes B'$ is a subalgebra of $A \otimes B$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $A,B$ be algebras and put the canonical algebra structure on $A \otimes B$, that is with multiplication given by $$(a \otimes b) (a' \otimes b') = (aa') \otimes (bb')$$

Let $A'$ a subalgebra of $A$ and $B'$ a subalgebra of $B$, say these are algebras over the complex numbers. I want to show that we can view $A'\otimes B'$ as a subalgebra of $A \otimes B$, that is I want to find an injective algebra homomorphism $A' \otimes B' \hookrightarrow A \otimes B$.

We have an obvious bilinear map $A'\times B' \to A \otimes B: (a, b) \mapsto a \otimes b$ and the universal property of the tensor product transforms this into a map
$$\psi: A' \otimes B' \to A \otimes B$$
with $\psi (a \otimes b) = a \otimes b$. How can I show that $\psi$ is injective? This looks like it acts as the identity but this is tricky because the tensors are taken in two different spaces and formally different.

Comment: The injectivity is a statement about tensor products of vector spaces so you can ignore the algebra structure. You can prove it explicitly by picking a basis or abstractly in two steps using flatness twice.